# Mapping not updating after function is called

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan

After calling this function:

```
  function WithdrawDividend(uint256 value) public {
    require(value <= _balances[msg.sender]);

    if (_RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] <= 0) {
        _SavedDividend[msg.sender] = _balances[address(this)].mul(value).div(100000000);  
        uint256 DividendsToBurn = _SavedDividend[msg.sender].mul(10).div(10000);
        uint256 DividendstoDividend = _SavedDividend[msg.sender].sub(DividendsToBurn);

        _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].sub(DividendstoDividend).sub(DividendsToBurn);
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(DividendstoDividend);
        _balances[address(0)] = _balances[address(0)].add(DividendsToBurn);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(DividendsToBurn);

        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, DividendstoDividend);
        emit Transfer(address(this), address(0), DividendsToBurn);

        _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = 1;
        ClaimTime[address(msg.sender)] = now;

    } else {
        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, 0);
    }

 }
```

Everything successfully works - the balances are updated and the transactions are sent. However, the _RestrictedFromDividend never changes to 1 and I don't understand why. How can I make sure it changes to 1 after this has happened?

Comment: I usally emit events at the end of the function,  try first 
        _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = 1;
        ClaimTime[address(msg.sender)] = now; and them emit Events

Comment: "When" in the transaction you emit events doesn't matter.

Comment: @manilpwn You may have to share more details about how you're testing this. Either the whole transaction succeeds or it is reverted, so if you're seeing changes to `_balances` when you call this function, then there must also be a change to `_RestrictedFromDividend`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `event` like

```
contract yourContract {
  event RestrictedFromDividendEvent(
    uint RestrictedFromDividend
  );

  mapping(address => uint) public _RestrictedFromDividend; // did you put this in public to have a getter

  // in your function

    _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = 1;
    emit RestrictedFromDividendEvent(
      _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)]
    );

  // end in your function
}
```

If it’s does not working there is a side effect somewhere in your execution.
But with events like the code above you can log easily your execution flow.